# CSRF validation using Tomcat 6 without using external packages

Tags: jsf, tomcat6, csrf

CSRF protection for a JSF based web app and Tomcat6 backend without using any external packages.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF has already builtin protection against [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) by the `javax.faces.ViewState` hidden field which is to be linked with the state of the component tree in the server side. If this hidden field is missing or contains a wrong value, then JSF simply won't process the POST request. On JSF 1.x the key is only a bit too easy to guess, see also [JSF impl issue 812](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-812) and [JSF spec issue 869](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-869). This is fixed in JSF 2.1.

Your major concern should be [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). A succesful XSS attack can form a source for a guaranteed-to-be-succesful CSRF attack. To avoid XSS, ensure that you don't redisplay user-controlled input with `<h:outputText escape="false" />`. Other than that, JSF will already by default escape HTML entities.

Comment: @BalusC i read a lot of CSRF questions here on stackoverflow. i'm not 100% sure, if i had understood the `javax.faces.ViewState` correctly... is it true, that there is NO NEED to check the State in my bean, that it's working automatically? (i have always just read from the hidden input field with the `javax.faces.ViewState` but in no post what i have to do in a bean)...  thx

Comment: ok... i tested it with firebug... and i got a `javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException` - ignore my question ;)